# how i can disable gif animation in android webview?

Tags: android, webview

I work on android browser project

Many sites use GIF animation an ad. How i can disable GIF animation in android webview ?

Comment: You can disable gif animation from android, but you can disable javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just inject a javascript to freeze the gifs recursively once your web page finishes loading. Heres how you do it,

1. First copy this javascript to your `assets` folder(If folder not available
   then create folder in `res` directory) - [gif_freezer.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B34i3ys_1kPSZnBwYkpTNWdtcVk/view?usp=sharing)
2. Add this method inside your class,

```
private void injectScriptFile(WebView view, String scriptFile) {
        InputStream input;
        try {
            input = getAssets().open(scriptFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
```

```
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
                "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
                // Tell the browser to BASE64-decode the string into your script !!!
                "script.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                "parent.appendChild(script)" +
                "})()");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

3. Inside `onPageFinished` method put below code,

   ```
   injectScriptFile(view, "gif_freezer.js");
   view.loadUrl("javascript:freezeAllGifs();");
   ```

   Thats all...

Comment: Thanks Prasad but my app crashed after do that

Comment: @Saiedfathehi, What does the crash says?